# Jmeter retrieve specific portion of SamplerData from SampleResult

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm trying to retrieve a specific portion of the `SamplerData` from the `SampleResult`.

Here's my current output:

```
GET https://google.com/

GET data:
hello world

[no cookies]
```

What i want is specifically the `hello world` inside the `GET data` section.

I have the following BackendListener code:

```
@Override
public void handleSampleResults(List<SampleResult> list, BackendListenerContext backendListenerContext) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String fileName = "C:\\projects\\sampleResults.csv";
    try {
        list.forEach(sampleResult -> {
            stringBuilder.append(sampleResult.getSamplerData());
            stringBuilder.append("\n");
        });
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
                new FileWriter(fileName));
        out.write(stringBuilder.toString());
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e ){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For particular your case it seems that you're trying to extract the body data of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler the easiest solution would be going for [sampleResult.getQueryString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSampleResult.html#getQueryString--) function

Demo:

[image]

However I fail to see the need of implementing your own Backend Listener here, you can achieve the same much faster and easier using [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin) plugin